# Render specific layers with python scripts in BGE

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks, layers

I have a game I'm making in the BGE that has one scene with a level on each layer and a main menu in another scene where the player can choose the level to play.  What I want is to have a script that will display only the layers needed for the level chosen.

Example: Player chooses level 1 from the menu scene.  Layer 1 of the levels scene contains level one and layer 5 of that same scene contains the character.  Load only the layers needed for the selection and none else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The game engine has no concept of layers beyond the active one and all the inactive ones.
So the simplest solution is to put the levels on different scenes and use the set-scene actuator.

Answer (score 0):

Add *Overlay Scene*

This adds another scene, and draws it on top of the current scene. It is good for interfaces: keeping the health bar, ammo meter, speed meter in an overlay scene makes them always visible.

[image: Scene Actuator]